# Name of specs and test with Jasmine 2 and Protractor 3.0.0 in the console

Tags: testing, console, jasmine, protractor

I have upgraded from Protractor 2.2.0 to Protractor 3.0.0, so Jasmine has been updated too.

Now I can't see in the console the name of specs and the test when I run the suites.

The conf.js has the option "isVerbose=true":

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    isVerbose: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 150000
},
```

When I had Jasmine 1.3 I could see the name of the test, asserts, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly the explanation, but a workaround solution that would also improve the console output:

- [`jasmine-spec-reporter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spec-reporter)

Install it and put the following reporter configuration code to the `onPrepare()` in your config:

```
var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
    displayStacktrace: 'all',
    displayPendingSpec: true,
    displaySpecDuration: true
}));
```